# at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Tags: android

i keep getting this error when i load up the emulator and click on the buttons which i have made

03-14 15:47:37.096: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

can so body explain what this error means

```
android:id="@+id/Linear Layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/Login_Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin Top="14dp"
    android:on Click="Login_on Click"
    android:text="My Training Plan" />




<Button
    android:id="@+id/Workouts_Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:on Click="Workouts_Button_on Click"
    android:text="Offensive Workouts" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Defensive_workouts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:on Click="Defensive_workouts_on Click"
    android:text="Defensive Workouts" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/Shot_Tracker_Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:on Click="Shot_Tracker_Button_on Click"
    android:text="Shot Tracker"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/About_Basketball_App_Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin Top="163dp"
    android:on Click="About_Basketball_App_Button_on Click"
    android:text="About Basketball App" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/contact Basketball app_Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:on click="contact Basketball app_on Click"
    android:text="Contact Basketball app" />
```

<

Comment: It means that you should post the full red part of the error because this is incomplete. Also post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you Declared above  activity classes in AndroidManifest.xml. i think it maybe not declared in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/your_app_name"
        android:name=".YourActivity" >
    </activity>
```